# Implementing Lexical editor on Vue 2

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, lexicaljs

I know there's Lexical-Vue that is built around Vue 3. But I want to try implementing it on Vue 2 app and it's apparently not working well.

The error says I need an appropriate loader for Lexical module but I'm not quite sure what it wants. My questions are, is the error from my Vue code or webpack? if then, what are the suggested solutions?

```html
<template>
  <div ref="editorRef"></div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld'
import { createEditor } from 'lexical'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  },
  mounted: function () {
    const config = {
      namespace: 'lex'
    }
    const editor = createEditor(config)
    editor.setRootElement(this.$refs.editorRef)
  }
}
</script>
```

```
 error  in ./node_modules/lexical/Lexical.dev.js

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (8753:13)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| 
|   exportJSON() {
|     return { ...super.exportJSON(),
|       type: 'paragraph',
|       version: 1

 @ ./node_modules/lexical/Lexical.js 8:57-84
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/App.vue
 @ ./src/App.vue
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main.js
```

```json
{
  "name": "lexical-test-vue",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A Vue.js project",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js",
    "start": "npm run dev",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue src",
    "build": "node build/build.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "lexical": "^0.6.0",
    "vue": "^2.5.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.1",
    "babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props": "^2.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-jsx": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx": "^3.5.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.3.2",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
    "chalk": "^2.0.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "eslint": "^4.15.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^10.2.1",
    "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^5.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^3.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^4.0.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.6.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "node-notifier": "^5.1.2",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "ora": "^1.2.0",
    "portfinder": "^1.0.13",
    "postcss-import": "^11.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.0.8",
    "postcss-url": "^7.2.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.0",
    "semver": "^5.3.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.6",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "vue-loader": "^13.3.0",
    "vue-style-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.2",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.9.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 6.0.0",
    "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

Comment: [That one](https://github.com/facebook/lexical)? It seems to be made for React even.

Comment: @kissu Well it says it is not limited to react tho

Comment: Did you try with Babel v7 ? Or maybe you could disable transpiling of `lexical` package ?